# I need help adding a simple math captcha to my contact form for a website

Tags: php, captcha, contacts

i want to add a simple math captcha to my php form,,,

this is the complete form code but it doesnot work.

here is a link to the code: http://thefairygodsister.com/testtest/index%20-%20Copy.txt

Comment: 404 - the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps to take are:
Lets say it is an add 2 numbers kind of math

```
$num1 = rand(15,50);
$num2 = rand(2,9);
$salted_answer = $num1+num2 + 187; //thats some salt
```

put the salted_answer into a hidden input on your form.

when checking:

```
if ($_POST['salted_answer'] - 187 == $_POST['answer']) { 
  echo "all is good";
  // do your processing 
}
```

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a "faux" maths captcha like [here](http://www.fizzwebdesign.co.uk/blog/php-contact-form-free-download/) that works on the very simple principal that the text needed to be inputted is fixed and indicated in an image - works perfectly at stopping bots sending you random emails without over complicating it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.